# Laravel limiting access to route

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-passport, laravel-controller

I am trying to implement a basic image fetch system for my website. Already created a route that returns me the image.

what concerns me is that i want that route to be only accessible by certain controllers.

Tried to search it and found out passport might be viable option but it's pretty complex for this app. Are there any possible options ?

EDIT:
Sorry for providing insufficient information. I want the route to be accessible only by CONTROLLERS, not by anyone who enters the route url to address bar. Like using it as an api maybe.

Comment: Use laravel middleware

Answer (score 0):

There several ways to achieve that, you can use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware), you can consider using packages like [entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) which also require you to have some knowledge about using middleware. or use [laravel Auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication)

Answer (score 0):

create a table add all the routes in that table and then check the allowed route in AppService provider.

$routename = Request::route()->getName();
$allowed_route = AllowedRoutes::where("route","=",$routename)->count();

if($allowed_route == 0)
  exit();